# problem lose class address when update composer 1 to 2

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

i have problem when install or update composer.
When the composer is updated and generated, the autoload file for example autoload_classmap.php changes and no class or file is found. I do not know how to solve. Thanks for the help.

composer.json file

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^3.1",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "larabook/gateway": "^3.4",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "morilog/jalali": "3.*",
    "shetabit/payment": "^4.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/sail": "^0.0.5",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "platform-check": false
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
```

}

and when update composer say: not found class App/ClearingHourTime

class file is :

```
    <?php

namespace App;

abstract class Enum {
    static function getKeys() {
        $class = new \ReflectionClass(get_called_class());
        return array_keys($class->getConstants());
    }
}

abstract class ClearingHourTime extends Enum {
    const OPERATION = [
        UserType::USR       =>  0,
        UserType::ADM       =>  72,
        UserType::IND_LAW   =>  72,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have an issue with ClearingHourTime.php, in that file as you are declaring two classes. I think that this practice does not meet psr4 standard, and you are loading app/ under psr4.

To solve this problem you have two options (use only one).

1. add "classmap": ["app/ClearingHourTime"]

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers.php",
    ],
    "classmap": ["app/ClearingHourTime"],
....
}
```

2. add "app/ClearingHourTime" to files. like

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers.php",
        "app/ClearingHourTime.php"
    ],
....
}
```

I hope this help

Comment: i used this but say: 
Could not scan for classes inside "app/ClearingHourTime" which does not appear to b  
  e a file nor a folder

Comment: I had a typo in files section, extension file was missing. I have corrected it

Comment: thanks for the reply. I forgot to say that my file name is enum.php and it has multiple abstract classes.
I create the class in a separate file and add it to the "autoload->files" , it works. Do I do this for all classes in the enum file?

Comment: That's a posible solution. If you are in Laravel and let then inside a folder in app/ then rename your files as the class inside in PascalCase.php then composer will  autoload your classes via psr4, if the namespace is correct.

Comment: Thanks Manuel. I do this. But I need a lot of class files to do this. I have to do this